# Insert data at end of worksheet with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, insert, analysis

I'm working with a data analysis and I have a question that I can't solve, I have 2 .xlsx sheets, both are the same, only with data in different columns, I wanted to add the data from sheet 2, at the end of sheet 1

First I imported the two files

```
file_excel  = pd.read_excel("feedback.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
file_insert  = pd.read_excel("insert_fed.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

file_excel
```

and returned me

```
Number  Color
0   White
14  Black
0   White
13  Black
6   Red
7   Red
4   Red
12  Black
9   Black
6   Red
12  Black
```

and then I ran the second file

```
file_insert

Número  Cor
13  Black
9   Black
14  Black
2   Red
9   Black
9   Black
3   Red
13  Black
8   Black
11  Black
13  Black
```

And I wanted the code to 'add' these two files and it would return me this

```
Number  Color
0   White
14  Black
0   White
13  Black
6   Red
7   Red
4   Red
12  Black
9   Black
6   Red
12  Black
13  Black
9   Black
14  Black
2   Red
9   Black
9   Black
3   Red
13  Black
8   Black
11  Black
13  Black
```

Is there any way to do it using pandas?

Comment: Try: `pd.concat(file_excel, file_insert)`.

Comment: I tried to run and it returned this error: 'TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"'

Comment: I did some tests and it was just putting '[]': pd.concat([file_excel, file_insert])

Comment: You are right, @Wiko: The brackets were missing. Sorry about that: I always forget the brackets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your excelfiles/sheets have different headers, so make sure first that the two dataframes have the same columns (by using [**`pandas.DataFrame.columns`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html)) then use [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Try this :

```
file_insert.columns= file_excel.columns

out_df= pd.concat([file_excel, file_insert], ignore_index=True)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out_df)

    Number  Color
0        0  White
1       14  Black
2        0  White
3       13  Black
4        6    Red
5        7    Red
6        4    Red
7       12  Black
8        9  Black
9        6    Red
10      12  Black
11      13  Black
12       9  Black
13      14  Black
14       2    Red
15       9  Black
16       9  Black
17       3    Red
18      13  Black
19       8  Black
20      11  Black
21      13  Black
```